# WPF DependencyProperty Binding Changed

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

Simple question, but I don't find any answer on the web :

I have a `DependencyProperty` in a custom control, and would like to know when someone bind to it.
Is there any way?

I first thought of using a `PropertyChangedCallback`, but it doens't work in every case.
For instance, if the default value for my `DependencyProperty` is 0, and the value bound is also 0, then the `PropertyChangedCallback` doens't fire.

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Comment: Why do you want to know this? I cannot think of a use-case.

Comment: I can only ask the same question as Dennis. Do you want to control who is allowed to databind? Do you want to reject some databindings? Do you want just to monitor databinding?

Comment: It is possible to get some information from the [`BindingOperations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.aspx) static class however probably not what you want (as far as I know there is no reason to want to get this information).

Comment: Hi Dennis and dowhilefor, Thanks for your comments. In fact, my use case is that I would like to retrieve a MetaData member which can be set above the source property of the binding (the model property). It works well when the value changes, but when it is set to 0 (the default value of the DP), none of my methods are called

Comment: @EvAlex Thanks for your answer proposal, I don't know why you withdrawed it? Overriding "SetBinding()" is an interesting way, but I don't like so much using the "new" keyword...

Comment: @AntoineJeanrichard He removed the answer simply because it didn't work. At least not for bindings which are established in XAML. SetBinding can't be overridden since it is not virtual, and replacing a method with `new` is not overriding. And then there is even no need for replacing the method. He could have written any other method in the derived class to establish the binding from code, since it has to be called explicitly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `CoerceValueCallback` is called multiple times, even if the value doesn't change.

It is called even when I do not set a `Binding`, but at least it is also called when I set one.

I think I'll use this for now, and check wether there is a `Binding` with `BindingOperations`.

If you have a better idea, I'll be please to learn it!

Thanks :)